# How to create a new project in Symfony 2 in Windows XP SP3?

Tags: symfony

I have installed and configured Symfony2 in my Windows OS, using XAMPP. It shows this welcome message:

[image: screenshot]

when I type the below URL in my browser:

```
 http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/
```

I want to create a new project, what should I do now? Is there any way to do this via GUI instead of the console.

I can tell you my path, where I have installed Symfony2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use netbeans IDE for development. 
In symfony2 For new project we want to create new bundle.
Then follow these steps.

1. Add your existing project to netbeans.
2. Under the project you can select Symfony2->runcommands (by right
   clicking the project)
3. use generate:bundle command from the window (use filter for finding
   the command).
4. Examples and documentations are there.

Comment: thanks for replying but I m using Dreamviewer as my IDE. can we not do this in Dreamviewer. also can you provide me any link of "Using symfony with help of netbeans" ?

Comment: I think this http://software-talk.org/blog/2012/06/symfony2-tutorial-netbeans-and-symfony2-setting-everything-up/ one is best for you ...

Comment: link is not opening. please check it

Comment: I have followed the tutorial of above link. But when I run my project "Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 " is appearing. please help me

Comment: Thank you so much for awesome chating. God Bless you :)